# ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

After I deploy my project on Heroku, I get for the following code in Firebug this error:

ReferenceError: SirTrevor is not defined

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  var instances = $('.sir-trevor-area'),
  l = instances.length;
while (l>=2) {
 instance = $(instances[l]);
 new SirTrevor.Editor({ el: instance, blockTypes: ["Video"], defaultType: "Video" });
 l--;
};
while (l>=1) {
 instance = $(instances[l]);
 new SirTrevor.Editor({ el: instance, blockTypes: ["Embedlylink"], defaultType: "Embedlylink" });
 l--;
};
while (l>=0) {
 instance = $(instances[l]);
 new SirTrevor.Editor({ el: instance, blockTypes: ["Heading", "Text", "Image", "Video", "Embedly"], defaultType: "Text" });
 l--;
};
});
</script>
```

Firebug highlights this line "

```
new SirTrevor.Editor({ el: instance, blockTypes: ["Heading", "Text", "Image", "Video", "Embedly"], defaultType: "Text" });
```

"

On localhost everything seems fine, no errors.
Anyone an idea what the problem could be?
Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated!

UPDATE:

SirTrevor is defined in sir-trevor.js which is successfully loaded via the Rails asset pipeline in the application.js file.

This is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require sir-trevor
//= require underscore.js
//= require eventable.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery.sidr.js
//= require_tree .
```

Before push to Heroku I do "rake assets:precompile" . On localhost everything seems fine.

The application.html.erb header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tt</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
```

Comment: Well, **`SirTrevor` is *not* defined**. Start there. 1) from *where* is `SirTrevor` to be defined and; 2) *is* the resource being successfully loaded? (Use web-browser developer tools to monitor the network requests.)

Comment: Check that all your Javascript files are loading properly.

Comment: The script containing the SirTrevor class isn't loading.

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: I guess it's a external script and you didn't precompile it.See in the console if it's not loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast feedback! The js files are loading, or to be precise the application.js file via the Rails asset pipeline.

Comment: @YvonC they may be loading, but are they loading in the order you want them to load? are they loading before the code above is executed?

Comment: @YvonC If the above code is running before the SirTrevor class (in your compiled file) then SirTrevor would be undefined. You *could* set `config.assets.compile = true` in your development.rb file and inspect the output. It would also be helpful if you shared your application.js file to see your require statements.

Comment: @KevinB Thx! Sorry, if I make here rookie mistakes. It seems like that the application.js is loaded afterwards. How can I make sure that the Rails asset pipeline is loaded before? I thought it does it per default.

Comment: @iamjpg I added the application.js file above.

Comment: @YvonC So, that looks fine. My next question, which might be answered from your response to Kevin, is the code you initially posted, is that a script block in the body of a page? Or is it in a file compiled by the asset pipeline? Where in your layout file is your `= javascript_include_tag :application` (pardon the haml if you use something else). Have you tried wrapping the above code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ // do something });`?

Comment: @iamjpg thank you for asking and helping! The code was in the body of the page. I moved it now in a js file, and the original error "sir-trevor is not defined" is gone. Unfortunately the sir trevor js is still not working in the UI, and a new error popped up in Firebug that says: "ReferenceError: _ is not defined" - This error points to jQuery/Sizzle.js code. -- The javascript_include_tag is in the header of the application.html.erb. I will update it above. Thx again!

Comment: @YvonC - No problem. That error is saying that Underscore.js isn't defined by the time something is executed depending on it. Try moving it up the require tree in your application.js. Also, wherever you're initially executing javascript from within your app, wherever your initial entry point is, try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function(){ // do something });`. This will prevent the code from executing until your compiled JS is available in the DOM.

Comment: @iamjpg Awesome! I had to play around a little bit with the hierarchy in the application.js but now it works. sir-trevor is finally running on heroku. THANK YOU! -  Firebug is still not happy though. It gives me a "TypeError: r is null" now.

Comment: @YvonC - I'm glad it's getting there. Good luck. Sometimes figuring out compiled JS issues is as tedious herding butterflies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to close the question a short roundup:
Thanks to the help of @iamjpg I finally figured it out.

First I eliminated all the javascript from the `<body>` and put into separate js files.
Then I adjusted the hierarchy in the application.js file. Sir-Trevor has dependencies to underscore.js and eventable.js, so they have to be higher than sir-trevor.js .

```
//= require jquery
//= require underscore.js
//= require eventable.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require sir-trevor
//= require jquery.sidr.js
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: In my situation I had the URL with CSS extension instead of a JS within the `<script>` tags. The editor did not warn about it...